# Use external exe in VB.NET project

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET program (I am working on this program).
I want to include an "external" exe file with my application while creating setup, and distribute it along with my software.  I want to copy "this exe" to the installation directory on user demand (when user clicks a button) using my software. I know I can add "this" exe as a "Resource" file but how can I copy it to the installation directory from "Resources"? How to access "this" exe after I create installer?
I tried this:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(My.Resources.abc, "C:\Users\LabOne\Desktop\abc.exe")
```

but this didn't work. Please Help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488160/how-to-include-another-project-console-application-exe-in-an-asp-net-website

Comment: Which software you are using to create `Setup` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the byte-data of the resource to a local filepath.

```
Dim resource As Byte() = My.Resources.File

Using fs As New FileStream("C:\file.exe", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
    fs.Write(resource, 0, resource.Length)
End Using
```