# How do I add a console C# application to a ASP.NET WebSite?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

My question is somewhat similar to this thread : [How to include another project Console Application exe in an Asp.Net website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488160/how-to-include-another-project-console-application-exe-in-an-asp-net-website/34098344#34098344)

I was however directed to ask a new question since my question wasn't answered and I could not comment on that thread.

So, my situation is this: I have a C# application that is compiled to an exe (for now). It works fine as a desktop app. Now I need to host the application on a website such that users can use it via their browsers.

I thought asp.net would be a good place to start and created a WebSite application. Now how do I go about referencing the C# application files so that I can call those methods from the new WebSite application?

I've tried to include post build events on the console app to copy the files to the WebSite folder, but I'm still unable to reference them.

Any other suggestions for what I'm trying to do also welcome :)

EDIT: I want to the application to be run on the server, the output of which I will then display on the user's browser.

Comment: Do you want the console application to execute on the client's computer, or on the server?

Comment: If you only need to execute the methods inside the Console app and not actually run the Console app itself, why don't you refactor your methods in a separate class library that you can reference from your web application?

Comment: Hey @mason, I want the functionality of the console app to be executed on the server

Comment: Would doing what @amuz said meet your needs?

Comment: hey @amuz , that sounds correct since I do not need the console application to run per se. I only need to get some input (from the user's browser), execute the methods of the application on the server which then produces output that I show on the user's browser again. What would be the best way of going about this?

Comment: @mason Yep I think so, I'm a bit of a newbie at this so I'm not 100% sure. If  i didn't have to actually run the console app on the server and instead simply call the methods that execute on the server, what would be your suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming I understand what you want:

1- You need to transfer your functionality to a `Class Library` project.

2- Add Reference to `DLL` in your website

3- Use the functionality as you like.

But, what you can't use is the functionality from assembly file of type `.exe` directly.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think it makes sense and I will try your suggestion. One last question, my original functionality needed references to external DLLs (Such as AForge, Emgu), so I am guessing I need to add those references to the Class Library project as well. My question is, once the Class Library project is complete, how many DLLs would I have to add a reference to in the WebSite project? Would it be 1 or 1 + how many ever external DLLs that I refer to?

Comment: @sidd, just one in the website and all other references should be add in the Class Library Project

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to run the console application and just need to used the methods that is defined inside the console application then I would refactor those methods inside a separate class library and then add a reference to the class library in my web application. Then build an interface into the webpage that calls the appropriate methods.

Here is a walkthrough from MSDN showing you how to [Create a web application project with a class library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc668164(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it looks like something that I start off with!

Answer (score 0):

You should not run the console application on the server as that is BAD! On Windows creating a whole new process for every request is not a good idea.

Refactor the console application to either take a TextWriter or (better in my opinion, but may take more refactoring) return the result in some logical fashion.

In an extreme case you could get away with just sending in Console.Out to the library and Response.Output.

It seems unlikely you would really just want to do that, but it may be the least thing you can get away with that isn't really bad.

Think along the lines of `Console.WriteLine("Hello World")` going to:

```
var lib = new MyLib(Console.Out);
lib.DoSomething();
```

ctor in this case is:

```
public MyLib(TextWriter writer)
{
  _writer = writer;
}
```

where DoSomething() is:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
   _writer.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```

On the web you would then output what you need to output and put your output there by first outputting a `<pre>` tag and then doing this:

```
var lib = new MyLib(Response.Output);
lib.DoSomething();


public string TellMeSomething()
{
  return "Hello World";
}
```

I almost don't want to recommend this as I think fully refactoring it to something would be better. So DoSomething becomes TellMeSomething and the implementation something like:

```
public string TellMeSomething()
{
  return "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: I think you'll be happy to know that I am siding towards creating a new class library and referencing them from the WebSite rather than running the console application on the server. That being said, thank you for your detailed answer!